# Refresh $scope changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

An ng-view is swapped out by routing. Here is some of the route and controller code

```
var containers = [];
angular.module('AContainer',['ngRoute']).config(
function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: containerListCtrl,
        templateUrl: '/closeAndUplift_containerList.html'
    });
}
);
function containerListCtrl($scope, $location){
    $scope.containers = containers;
}
```

Here is the div

```
<div id='containersDiv' ng-app='AContainer'>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Within this a view (closeAndUplift_containerList.html) has been loaded which displays an array of objects via a ng-repeat

```
<div>
<table>
    <thead>
    <th>Pallet id</th>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat='container in containers'>
        <td><a href='#/edit/{{container.index}}'>{{container.id}}</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem occurs when a change results from a jquery ajax callback. The xhr calls are contained in a separate library and a callback function is passed in. The callback is supposed to clear the list of containers. The callback executes this:

```
var activeScope = $('#containersDiv').scope();
activeScope.$apply( function(){
    activeScope.containers = [];
});
```

But nothing happens. The old values are still displaying.

EDIT:
I re-arranged the code to take advantage of $http as per Rishul's suggestion to make it work. The problem is that while it is a work-around, it doesn't really answer the question as to why the method I used did not work.
Can someone comment on whether his answer should be selected as solving the problem?

Comment: your view needs to have a controller which will have a scope

Comment: Out of interest: what'd you need a jquery callback for? Angular has some built in xhr request stuff.

Comment: The problem is that some of the xhr calls are contained in a separate library and a callback function is passed in. I originally didn't include it to keep the question simple but I now see it is relevant.

Comment: I re-arranged the code to take advantage of $http as per Rishul's suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a **$http** service to make ajax calls because this inbuilt angular js library will run a digest cycle on getting a response and as you modify the scope variables the view will also change.

in your case jquery callback will not trigger a $digest cycle hence view is not getting updated! please confirm if it works